# Sum of two indexes which are having same values with multi dimension Array

Tags: php, arrays

I am working with multi dimensional array is like below with php,

```
$return_array=   Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 3_Mar_2017
                [1] => 0
                [2] => 19
                [3] => 7
                [4] => 13
                [5] => 3
                [6] => 0
                [7] => 42
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => Yet to closed
                [1] => 0
                [2] => 0
                [3] => 0
                [4] => 0
                [5] => 1
                [6] => 0
                [7] => 1
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => 3_Mar_2017
                [1] => 0
                [2] => 7
                [3] => 0
                [4] => 0
                [5] => 0
                [6] => 0
                [7] => 7
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [0] => 4_Apr_2017
                [1] => 0
                [2] => 8
                [3] => 4
                [4] => 0
                [5] => 0
                [6] => 0
                [7] => 12
            )

      )
```

On 0th and 2nd indexs -> from sub array of that indexes -> 0th index are common "**3_Mar_2017**" ,I want to sum that two indexes and want result as shown below,

```
 $final_return = Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3_Mar_2017
                    [1] => 0
                    [2] => 26
                    [3] => 7
                    [4] => 13
                    [5] => 3
                    [6] => 0
                    [7] => 49
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Yet to closed
                    [1] => 0
                    [2] => 0
                    [3] => 0
                    [4] => 0
                    [5] => 1
                    [6] => 0
                    [7] => 1
                )    
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 4_Apr_2017
                    [1] => 0
                    [2] => 8
                    [3] => 4
                    [4] => 0
                    [5] => 0
                    [6] => 0
                    [7] => 12
                )

          )
```

My tried code with loop as below,

```
 $tem_array = array();
        $final_return = array();
        foreach ($return_array as $unique) {
            if (!in_array($unique[0], $tem_array)) {
                array_push($tem_array, $unique[0]);
                $final_return[] = $unique;
            } else {
                $index = array_search($unique[0], $tem_array);
                for ($i = 1; $i < count($unique); $i++) {
                    $final_return[$index][$i] = $final_return[$index][$i] + $unique[$i];
                }
            }
        }
```

but if array size will large then ,may be it will take time is there any simple solution.
can any person help me to get this required result with minimum code ? 
I will appreciate best answer.

Comment: `foreach` and `+` operator.

Comment: show here what you have tried

Comment: $tem_array = array();
        $final_return = array();
        foreach ($return_array as $unique) {
            if (!in_array($unique[0], $tem_array)) {
                array_push($tem_array, $unique[0]);
                $final_return[] = $unique;
            } else {
                $index = array_search($unique[0], $tem_array);
                for ($i = 1; $i <= count($unique); $i++) {
                    $final_return[$index][$i] = $final_return[$index][$i] + $unique[$i];
                }
            }
        }

Comment: I have used above code ,actual array will stored in $return_array ,it is working but if the array size will large then it may take time

Comment: please add the tried code to the post in proper layout. This will help readability and will make sure the post is useful after it has been answered.

Answer (score 1):

hope this is what you are looking for

```
$temp1 = array(); $result = array(); 
foreach ($myArray as $temp) { 
    if (!in_array($temp[0], $temp1)) { 
        array_push($temp1, $temp[0]); $result[] = $temp; 
    } else { 
        $id = array_search($temp[0], $temp1); for ($i = 1; $i <= count($temp); $i++) { 
        $result[$id][$i] = $result[$id][$i] + $temp[$i]; 
        } 
    } 
}
```

your first array would look like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 13
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 14
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 6
            [3] => 7
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 13
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 3
        )

)
```

and the result be like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 13
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 4
            [3] => 6
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 14
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 6
            [3] => 7
        )

)
```

Comment: you are most welcom